# How to store xml file on firebase hosting get url point to it?

Tags: reactjs, xml, firebase, sitemap, firebase-hosting

I have a React app that is stored in google Firebase with my custom domain (not the one that is provided by google Firebase)
I have created an xml file and want to store it on google Firebase and get its URL.

for example if my website domain is:
www.mywebsite.com
I want to upload file sitemap.xml to Firebase and get it stored there,
and to be able to access it through:
www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml

How can I upload that file and have access to it through that URL?

Comment: Have you tried starting with the instructions for Firebase Hosting?  Did you get stuck somewhere?  Is there something specific you don't understand?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: Yes, the hosting works properly, I only don't know how to add specific file (xml file) and get url link to it?

Comment: Did you place the XML file in the public folder along with all the other web content and deploy it?  There should be no trick or surprises here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload a `sitemap.xml`:

1. Place the `sitemap.xml` into the folder that you've configured as the `public` folder in your `firebase.json`, which is also the folder where you have your main `index.html` file.
2. Run `firebase deploy --only hosting`.

Now the `sitemap.xml` will be available on `www.mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml`.